# amazon DynamoDB query not working for boolean attributes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am using DynamoDB. Trying to query against Boolean attribute, does not work. Please find FilterExpression below:

```
  ExpressionAttributeNames:
   { '#userId': 'userId',
     '#accId': 'accId',
     '#isactive': 'isactive' },
  ExpressionAttributeValues:
   { ':40c393702cd711e89b7019ea9c7b109d': '40c39370-2cd7-11e8-9b70-19ea9c7b109d',
     ':false': false },
  FilterExpression: '#userId = :40c393702cd711e89b7019ea9c7b109d OR #accId = :40c393702cd711e89b7019ea9c7b109d AND #isactive= :false',
```

The above query should filter out inactive records, but they are included as well. What am I doing wrong here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how `#isactive = :false` should filter out inactive records but you have another problem: You'll need to mind the [precedence in conditions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.html#Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.Precedence). `AND` is evaluated before `OR`. So, your filter expression would evaluate to `true` even though `isactive` is `false` unless you enclose a condition in parentheses:

```
FilterExpression: "(#userId = :40c393702cd711e89b7019ea9c7b109d OR #accId = :40c393702cd711e89b7019ea9c7b109d) AND #isactive = true"
```